# Test for integrability of function

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be a function with
$\int^{\infty}_{0}f(t)dt<\infty$.

Does it follow that $\lim \inf_{r\to \infty}f(r)/f(2r)>2$?
(Strict inequality needed!)

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x\log(x)^2}$ for $x\geq e$, with $f(x)=0$ for $0\leq x<e$. Then $f$ is integrable on $[0,\infty)$, but
$$ \liminf_{r\to\infty}\frac{f(r)}{f(2r)}=\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{2r\log(2r)^2}{r\log(r)^2}=2\lim_{r\to\infty}\Big(\frac{\log r+\log 2}{\log r}\Big)^2=2$$